# Identifying groups/patterns in a random dataset using Matlab

Tags: classification, matlab, pattern-recognition

I have the datasets which may contain multiple patterns. The data needs to be classified based on grouping in the data. The figure below shows an example of the data. The circles around the data are manually drawn to indicate groups.

Any help to do this type of data classification using Matlab? Thanks.

[image]